# Put my web2py application online

Tags: python, web2py

I have been searching for ages for a simple guide to this but can't find anything. I've just finished my web2py application and I want to be able to access it from a different computer for testing. Can anyone give me a simple guide as to how to do this? I'm also on a windows machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To start a web2py application using the built-in rocket server it's as simple as this in a `cmd.exe` window after you `cd` into your web2py's application directory

```
python web2py.py --ip 172.25.116.10 --port 8000
```

Where `172.25.116.10` is the address you are listening on and 8000 is the tcp port.

Comment: Sorry completely forgot to mark this as correct worked perfectly thank you.